# Kill session on popup close until the closing of browser

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to show a popup about browser compatibility to the users visiting my website. I have used the popup in about 5 pages and it would be annoying for the users to see the same popup for more than once when they visit my website.  So I am thinking to use a session and kill it when the user closes the poup. IT should not be shown until the browser is restarted. Could someone tell me how it can be done. I know what can be done but not how? Thanks a lot inadvance!!

Comment: How about fixing the browser compatibility issues instead?

Comment: I am SO going to avoid your website.

Comment: Don't do that!  Unless of course you don't like your website visitors, or are competing with one of my sites, then by all means...

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys. I am going to solve all these compatibility issues soon. For the time being, i want to display the popup. My next task is to solve the browser issues. Anyways once gain, thanks all for the advice :)

Comment: Its going to be in Beta version for a while. I need this popup until i solve compatibility bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Definitely spend your time fixing the browser compatibility instead of learning how to control your popups.

2) Create a tiny cookie using plain javascript (or jquery wrapper) and store `bc_notice=1`. Then retrieve that cookie and if it's already set to 1 - don't show the popup.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to do that, place a cookie that will persist during browser's lifetime. If it doesn't exist, make one that says "A popup windows should be shown". After it's shown, modify that cookie using Javascript so it says "Ok, window shown, now I won't be used anymore".

Comment: Note that this might end up being mean to users who don't have cookies enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="javascript">

function setFlag()

{

     // Call Web Service or Ajax Method with your session Key

     // CallaMethod('ScreenDisplayed');

}

</script>

</head>

<body onbeforeunload="setFlag();">

</body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "pop-up" you mean something similar to the CNN edition selector that slides down from the top or like the SO "a new answer has been posted to this page" bar at the top of this page. An actual javascript window popup would be incredibly intrusive for something like this.

Show the message once. Once it is shown, store its status in a persistent cookie and never show it again. As an alternative, provide an X somewhere so the user can get rid of it and determine never to see it again. They don't want to see it in the first place, but if you have to show it... whatever.

Mostly - fix your issues. Don't spend time worrying about fancy ways to avoid fixing them.

Comment: if the issues are IE6 issues, I support his position of simply alerting the user that it's time to upgrade.  Too much developer time is wasted trying to support IE6.  I agree with using a cookie though.